# How to get Smart Time Ago to work with Handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars.js and http://pragmaticly.github.com/smart-time-ago/

I have this working:

```
<time class="timeago" datetime="2012-07-18T07:51:50Z"></time>
```

Demo it here: [Demo](https://c9.io/aaronkahlhamer/smart-time-ago/workspace/index.html)

---

But when I add the time within the logic for Handlebars as seen here...

```
<div id="handlebarsPlaceholder">This will get replaced by handlebars.js</div>
    <script id="aaronsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#messages}}
         <li>
            <a href="#messageID{{messageID}}">
                <time class="timeago" datetime="2012-07-18T07:51:50Z"></time>
                <strong>{{from}}</strong><br/>
                {{subject}}
            </a>
         </li>
        {{/messages}}
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

...it does not work.

What am I missing or is there an article that can lead me to an answer? I've search everywhere on google but must not have the right search terms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$('.timeago').timeago()` call won't find things inside a `<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">` because that `<script>` doesn't contain HTML (which is why we specifically don't use `type="text/html"` on our template containers).

All you need to do is call `.timeago()` on the HTML you get from filling in your template; something like this:

```
var t = Handlebars.compile($('#aaronsTemplate').html());
$('#handlebarsPlaceholder').html(t({ ... });
$('#handlebarsPlaceholder .timeago').timeago();
```

The last line is what you were missing.

Also, your HTML is a bit off, you have a stray `</div>` and you're missing an opening `<ul>` in your template; you should have something more like this:

```
<div id="handlebarsPlaceholder">This will get replaced by handlebars.js</div>
<script id="aaronsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{#messages}}
            <li>
                <!--... -->
            </li>
        {{/messages}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Demo (with a stripped down template): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/89Bwx/1/

Comment: Thanks! I added $('#handlebarsPlaceholder .timeago').timeago(); and it worked! And that's for the letting me know about the missing 'ul'.

Comment: Here's a few screenshots of it in action.
https://c9.io/aaronkahlhamer/smart-time-ago/workspace/time-ago.png
https://c9.io/aaronkahlhamer/smart-time-ago/workspace/markup.png